# Prevent Infection of USB drive

Tags: windows, security, usb-flash-drive, malware

I have a bootable USB drive full of computer repair tools. I would use it to repair a computer that might very well be infected by a virus or other malware. I would like to know how I can prevent malware from spreading to my USB drive.

Notes:

- There are already questions about this that are about spread from USB to COMPUTER but I could not find any about COMPUTER to USB.
- This solution would have to be Windows-based but not computer specific.

Comment: Write protect the device in question.

Comment: Any write protection solution I can find either is pc specific or requires solutions that are permanent and cannot be undone. I want this to be un-doable in some way.

Comment: That is a possibility, but I was hoping to avoid having to do that every single time I work on a pc...

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. It sounds however like that's something only a "advanced virus" could do. What I mean is it seems like not much malware would be able to do that.

Comment: Not every pc has a disk drive nowadays. Also its 32 gigs... so...

Comment: "Any write protection solution I can find... cannot be undone.  I want this to be un-doable in some way."  You've asked for a solution which is both unchangeable but also changeable.  I've created an answer below which may satisfy - use a USB with a write protect switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buy a USB stick with a physical "Write Protected" switch.  I've used one in the past and been unable to casually write to it while the switch was in the proper position.  Of course, if you want to boot from it, you have to use an OS tolerant of the read-only state, like a LiveCD.  I don't know what OS you're using currently, but you have some options.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know those existed.

Comment: Related : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4248/how-reliable-is-a-write-protection-switch-on-a-usb-flash-drive

Comment: It's less about it being unchangeable but also changeable but changeable but hard to change. Your solution was perfect though.